# How to adjust brightness using UISlider on custom camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios9

iOS 8 Camara features to adjust brightness while tap on camara.

[image]

I have also tried this code but not working.

```
  AVCaptureDevice *device =[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

  AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains deviceWhiteBalance;// = [device deviceWhiteBalanceGains];

 AVCaptureWhiteBalanceTemperatureAndTintValues tempAndTint = [device temperatureAndTintValuesForDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:[device deviceWhiteBalanceGains]];

tempAndTint.temperature = (slider.value*100)*10000/100;
if (slider.value < 0.50) {
    tempAndTint.tint = -(slider.value*100)*150/100;
}
else{
    tempAndTint.tint = (slider.value*100)*150/100;
}


deviceWhiteBalance = [device deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues:tempAndTint];
[device chromaticityValuesForDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:deviceWhiteBalance];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    AVCaptureDevice *device =[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (device) {
        [device setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:deviceWhiteBalance completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {

        }];
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it's exposure, not brightness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. and get the every new changes which support below the ios version 8.0

[AVCamMenual - ios 8 Camera features](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html)

[image]